# Selenium "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

which returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

If I run with `options.add_arguments("--headless")`, I don't receive any error. Unfortunately, I can't really run what I'd like to in headless. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

ChromeDriver isn't finding the port it needs to talk to Chrome over.

Solution : 
Check your chrome browser version and then you can download chromedriver from the below location.

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Useful link :
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection

Comment: In `usr/bin` I see that the Google Chrome version is Google Chrome 78.0.3904.108 and the Chrome Driver is ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.108, though

Comment: Are you running your test in  headless mode. if not then add  options.add_argument('--headless')

Comment: No, I'm specifically trying to use Chrome out of headless mode. Could it have to do with the display?

Comment: @pete were you able to find a solution? I am in the same boat, trying to run Chrome in non-headless mode while using xvfb and getting the same error